# How can I create a NestJS graphql server with dynamic schema with respect to user?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, nestjs-config, nestjs-graphql

I am using **Nest JS** for server and new to **Graphql**, I want to create a graphql server but schema defines in Graphql module in app.module. I am using schema first appraoch.

[app.module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48RsX.png)
in importing **Graphql Module**, **typepaths** property defines to create **typings** from schemas present in any path.

but I don't have any particular schema because I want my user to enter any thing he want and fetch data using Graphql where typings should be with respect to particular user.

Things I tried:
I tried to rewrite the schema using filesystem methods from service but to update typings from schema nest server needs to restart to generate typings again.

please anyone give me a guide or any approach how can I achieve dynamic typings. I want a server which shows a graphql playground but user should be allow to query with respect to their data.

like for user 1 this highlighted box can be a schema but for different user this schema should be with respect to himself:[user 1 should see this schema and should query only using this schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qWXI.png)

Related Images are attached in link.

Any guide would be appreciated, Thanks!